# matchscore method always return 0 using the "doTrackIdAsync" method with the Gracenote mobile android GNSDK

Tags: android, gracenote

I have been playing with the new Gracenote mobile android GNSDK and while using the "doTrackIdAsync" method, I have noticed that the response has a method matchscore()  and a method matchconfidence() which have been recentky added but they always returns respectively 0 and an empty string. I was wondering if there was an option that needed to be turned on in order to get those values returned. Are those method already implemented or they are not available to use yet ? I have not seen any mention of it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The match score and confidence are only returned while doing a text match. I guess that in your case you are doing a fingeprint only lookup which explains why you get empty score and confidance.

If you add text or metadata to your query, you will get back those scores which will tell you the closeness between the text you provided and the text of the result that was returned.

Comment: Thank you clear response. Is there any date for the release of the GNSDK 1.2?

Comment: This feature will probably never be used to qualify the matching rate when you are using fingerprints. Nothing is planned for a future release AFAIK. Normaly you should not such such a value anyway as the result list that is returned is already sorted from best to worse. Do you mind giving more details about how you would use such a feature?

Comment: Sure, the reason i was interested by that matching rate is that i did realized that music-Id and musicStreamId  were sometimes returning me result that were not wrong. If We had an accuracy rate, we could decide if we wanted to use the result or nor. In the application that we are building,we use musicId and musicIdStream in the background a lot so it is really important for us to only accept the result if we have a high percentage of certainty(like 95% and up) that the result is accurate. If you want , I can give your specific examples where we received the wrong result

Comment: Ok i will put the songs file in a dropbox folder sometimes today so you can have them to play with it

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have added some mp3 files in a dropbox directory https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6hcfxdjl86xaum0/AADjFdunBSUAcatQiCB4YKTja?dl=0

Comment: all the files in that directory have the wrong song title and artist. Take a look and get back to me if you have any questions or if you figure out what is wrong. Again we think it would be nice if there was an matching  rate that we can use to avoid cases like that

Comment: can you tell me a litle more about what you try to achieve in order for me not to lose too much time trying to solve the wrong issue? For example, with those files... you are trying to id them using? mid-stream? mid-file? on what platform? give me an example on one of those files? What is the result you get returned and what is the expected result? Thanks.

Comment: Hey @jonx sorry for the late response. The files that are in that directory when I use the mid-file to identify them, it gives me the wrong artist and wrong title. Like I said we run the mid-file automatically on the music files on the user mobile device and we  change the meta data of the file if the mid-file return a successful result. It is becomes a problem for the user though if we change the file thinking we have the right information and we don't.

Comment: Especially because we do that in bulk, It can be really confusing for the user because after we have ran the mid-file, the feel like they lost some music files when in fact they files just have the wrong artist and title. I was just wondering if there was a matching rate that we could rely on to dismiss result if the matching rate is low.

Comment: Hey @jonx , Since yesteday I am getting th following error when using the musicId-file. " Hello Error: [130] Please contact Gracenote ODP 04374[ Name: ***][App:***]support.[Gracenote Error 130/74]." Can you please tell me what is the issue? is that a quota limit for request? What can I do now in order to resolve it?

Comment: might be a daily quota (you still have the error the next day?) or your client id has expired (they expire after a year)

Comment: ah okay get it . I think it just expire. Should I just create a new one then? @jonx

Comment: also do you had a chance to look at the files i have put on dropbox?

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I was wondering if there was a way to get the list of all top music genres(level-0) used by the GNResultReady Object GNSearchResultReady Object... We are trying to map them with the music genres that we are using internally

Comment: GNSDK has list APIs. There is also one sample normally that shows how to do. Please post a new question next time for new topics. Also, I've not yet had the time to look into your sample files. No idea when I will find it... Will keep you posted...